# Prove that $C_0(X)/Y$ is isometrically isomorphic to $C_0(F)$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

> Let $X$ be a normal locally compact topological space, $F\subseteq X$ a closed subset.
>
> 1. Prove that $Y=\{f\in C_0(X):f(x)=0\ \text{for every}\ x\in F\}$ is closed in $C_0(X)$.
> 2. Prove that $C_0(X)/Y$ is isometrically isomorphic to $C_0(F)$.

My definition for $C_0(X)=\{f\in C(X):\forall\varepsilon>0, \{x:|f(x)|\geq\varepsilon\}$ is compact$\}$.

So, I wasn't able to make any progress in the first bullet. As for the second one, my attempt is as follows:
We define $\phi:C_0(X)/Y\to C_0(F)$ by $\phi(\bar f)=f|_F$. This map is a well defined linear operator, and also $1-1$. I tried showing its onto, by taking $g\in C_0(F)$ and using Tietze's extension theorem, but I can't prove that the extension is in $C_0(X)$. Moreover, I wasn't able to show it is indeed a isometry.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do the assumptions normal + locally compact include Hausdorff?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes they do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to see that the one-point compactification of a locally compact normal space is still normal, and hence the Tietz extension theorem applies.

Now let $X^*=X\cup\{\infty\}$ be the one-point compactification of $X$, for any $f\in C_0(F)$, we can extend $f$ to be $\bar f \in C(F\cup\{\infty\})$ by defining $\bar f(\infty)=0$. Note that $\bar f$ is still continuous and $F\cup \{\infty\}$ is closed in $X^*$. Therefore by Tietz extension theorem, we can extend $\bar f$ to be a continuous function $\tilde f$ on $X^*$, such that $\sup \tilde f = \sup \bar f = \sup f$. Further we have $\tilde f|_X\in C_0(X)$, and $\sup \tilde f|_X = \sup \tilde f = \sup f$. This shows both surjectivity and isometry at the same time.

Comment: Why is the restriction to $X$ in $C_0(X)$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you referring to $\tilde f|_X$? That's because by definition, any element in $f\in C_0(X)$ is a function on $X$ (not $X^*$, although it's really just continuous functions on $X^*$ that vanishes at $\infty$).

Comment: The one-point compactification of any locally compact space is normal.

Comment: I understand why $\tilde f\in C(X)$ but why is it in $C_0(X)$? I mean why is it that for every $\varepsilon>0$, the set $\{x||f(x)|\geq \varepsilon\}$ compact?

Comment: Because $\{x:|\tilde f(x)|<\epsilon\}$ is a neighborhood of $\infty$ as $\tilde f(\infty)=0$. By definition of 1-pt compactification, the cocompact sets of $X$ union $\infty$ form a neighborhood basis of $\infty$ in $X^*$. So $\{x:|\tilde f(x)|\ge\epsilon\}$ is a closed subset of compact subset and hence compact. This is a very standard technique to understand $C_0(X)$ in terms of $X^*$.

Comment: @Justauser I still can't see why this proves the isometry. How do you see that $||f||_{C_0(F)}=||\phi(f)||_{C_0(X)/Y}=\operatorname{inf}_{g\in Y}||f-g||_{C_0(X)}$?

Comment: There are some general theorems about homomorphisms between $C^*$-algebras that can be applied, but it also follows concretely in this case.  Note that we have trivially $\|f-g\|_X\ge \|f-g\|_F = \|f\|_F$, hence $\inf \|f-g\|\ge \|f\|_F$. For the other direction, we lift $f|_F$ to be $\tilde f|_X$ such that $\|\tilde f|_X\|=\|f|_F\|$. And $\tilde f|_X$ is among $f-g$.

Comment: @Justauser Can I ask for a hint for the first bullet? am I supposed to use the same argument with the one point compactification?